# Django - automate CRUD from models (DRY approach)?

Tags: django, crud, dry

*I am new to Django but not to developing.*

I need to make an application in which user can do CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete). This functionality should apply to all models and the fields for Create & Update will be auto-generated from model attributes.

What I describe is pretty much the **functionality that comes with the Admin page**. However, I want to use it in my own app instead of using the Admin app.

For example, let's suppose we have `Author` and `Book` models:

(`models.py`)

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I suppose that the above information (models) could be enough for CRUD operations, without repeating code of the same logic for each model. I am aiming at a functionality like in admin page where all you have to do is register your model.

I am aware of *ModelForm* and *Generic Views* but while they help avoiding hard-coding form fields, I have not found a non-repetitive coding approach. I would like to avoid approaches like the following where same code is being duplicated for each model:

(`forms.py`)

```
from django import forms
from todo.models import Author, Book

class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

(`views.py`)

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from.forms import AuthorForm, BookForm
from.models import Author, Book

class AuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Author
    form_class = AuthorForm
    ...

class BookCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm
    ...
```

So, what is the best approach for a DRY CRUD solution (like in Admin page)? Am I missing any Django features?

Comment: You're missing [modelform_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/models/) and the ability to add arguments to [`as_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf) that are also available declaratively. So you could instantiate all this from urlpatterns construction, using [`apps.get_models()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models) to seed the models.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate by posting an answer with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Putting my explanation in the comment together, you would get something like this:

```
from django.views import generic
from myapp.apps import MyAppConfig
from django.forms import modelform_factory


urlpatterns = []
for model in MyAppConfig.get_models():
    create_url = path(
        f"{model.__class___.__name__.lower()}/create",
        generic.CreateView.as_view(
            form_class=modelform_factory(model=model, fields='__all__'),
            template_name=f"{model._meta.app_label}/create.html",
            model=model
        ),
   ),
   list_url = path(
        f"{model.__class__.__name__.lower()}/",
        generic.ListView.as_view(
            template_name=f"{model._meta.app_label}/list.html",
            model=model
        ),
    ),
   ...
   urlpatterns.extend([create_url, list_url, read_url, update_url, delete_url])
```

So the principle is to use the generic view and model form factory, to generate standard crud views, derive path names from model name and use one template per view, in the application (derived from model's app_label).

Using the documentation I linked before, you should be able to piece things together.

Comment: I get an error: `Calling modelform_factory without defining 'fields' or 'exclude' explicitly is prohibited`. I tried to add an empty exclude list but did not help.

Comment: Same as in your model forms: `fields = '__all__'`.